# Selecting a row from HTML table and edit/delete it

Tags: web-applications, mako, turbogears, turbogears2, sprox

I have created a html table (using TG2.1 with mako) for a file from MySQL db.
Now I would like to provide for "Edit / Delete" a particular row (record), by selecting that row in table.

Note that I am not using SQLAlchemy, since I am more comfortable with SQL query-generation myself. I am directly using MySQLdb and executing queries, fetching resultset, etc.

I checked the docs of TG 2.1, which shows how to edit a Wiki Page by using Sprox library.
But I do not have a data-model, so I think I can't use Sprox.

Is there any other way to "identify the row selected by user" and "give an interface for editing it"

Answer (score 0):

So, when I'm outputting the table row in my template code I would also output a link to edit, and a link (or button!) to delete the object, specifying the ID in the url string.

Creating a URL that looks like

/things/edit/2

for record id 2.

Then create an edit method in your controller. It will take two parameters: the first being self (of course), and the second being the ID you passed up above (2, in this case).